# Is it posible to create a default implementation of willSet on a class protocol

Tags: ios, swift, protocols, protocol-extension

What I am trying to do is notify an object when it gets replaced as a delegate from my services object. I was wondering if there is a way to create a default implamintation of willSet so I do not have to duplicate code for each service object I create:

```
protocol BaseServiceDelegate: class {
    var delegate: BaseServiceDelegate? {get set}
    func servicesDelegateReferanceWasRemoved(service: BaseServiceDelegate)
}

extension BaseServiceDelegate {

    willSet(newValue){
        delegate?.servicesDelegateReferanceWasRemoved(self)
        self = newValue
    }
}
```

Im really not sure where to start with the syntax of the extension or if this is possible. The error with the above code is on the 'willSet' line: "Exspected declaration"
Thank you for your time
still not sure if its possible but i made some edits to insure you have access to the delegate object defined

Comment: I think you may want to spend a little more time on this document to better understand protocols and their extension: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH25-ID267

Comment: Are you trying to make a [property observer] work for an entire instance or just create a default function to be executed inside a property observer?

Comment: So a `BaseServiceDelegate` has a `delegate` property with type `BaseServiceDelegate`? :)

Comment: impossible, because self is immutable.

Comment: Hey so imutable is not an problem as this is defined as a class protocol, and what i was thinking was that you conform to this protocol if others can set themselves as your delegate and you inform them when their reference is being overriden. the correct way of doing this may be building out the same functionality in a base class rather then a base protocol

Comment: mutation protocol extension http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32488726/protocol-extension-mutating-function

Comment: that protocol mutates properties not self. It is impossible to do `self = ...`

Comment: i mean that is part of the question, it doesnt have to be done that exact way. is there a way to achieve what that code is trying to do. After fiddling with it for a while a base class seems to be the way not the base protocol. I will post code if I get to a point I am happy with

Comment: The biggest problem you have is that you can't overload `=` which is how you assign a new instance to a reference. So there is no way to do this automatically. You can obviously create a static function in a `protocol` or `class` that takes in the old and new instance, calls a delegating function of the old instance and returns the new instance. The result of this function is then used to assign the new reference.

Comment: Yes, i was hoping there was somethign slick i was just missing around that. but i guess not :(

Answer (score 0):

the best answer I can find is to define a base Protocol:

```
protocol baseProtocol {
    func informOfAction()
}
```

then implement this on your delegates that would like to also have this functionality:

```
protocol childProtocol: baseProtocol {
    func somethingHappend()
    func somethingElseHappend()
}
```

and when you create the object that conforms to childProtocol have the custom will set there

```
var delegate: childProtocol? {
    willSet{
        delegate?.informOfAction()
    }
}
```

not as nice as i was looking for but not too bad, an extra 3 lines on all my objects similar to 'delegate'