# Can we edit properties of "let" protocol properties in Swift?

Tags: swift, swift-protocols, let

I have a code like this (play in a playground:

```
protocol ServiceProtocol {
    var enabled: Bool { get set }
}

class Service: ServiceProtocol {
    var enabled: Bool = false
}

class A {
    let service = Service()
}

class B {
    let service: ServiceProtocol = Service()
}

let a = A()
let b = B()

a.service.enabled = false
b.service.enabled = false // <-- the error is here: Cannot assign to property: 'service' is a 'let' constant
```

If I reference `service` as a `Service` (class `A`), everything works as expected. In class `B`, with `service` being a `ServiceProtocol`, I have the error:

**Cannot assign to property: 'service' is a 'let' constant**

It is a nonsense to me, as I am not trying to assign anything to `service`: I am only trying to assign a property of `service`. `enabled` being `get set`, I should be able to assign it, like in `A`.

If I declare `service` as a `var` in class `B`, the error disappears.

Any ideas?

Comment: Possibly helpful: [Protocol Extension, Mutating Function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32488726/1187415).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is because classes, structs and enums can implement your protocol so the compiler doesn't know if it is a reference type or value type. You can restrict your protocol to be for only classes and your code will work

```
protocol ServiceProtocol: AnyObject {
    var enabled: Bool { get set }
}
```

And now

```
b.service.enabled = false
```

compiles fine

Comment: Works fine, thank you!!! The error message could be maybe a little improved  

Comment: I would make a notice here that `AnyObject` yields an Objective-C object. While this is most of the times not a problem, I would say this is an important thing to know. To keep it as a "Swift-only" object you could simply mark it as `protocol ServiceProtocol: class {}`.

Comment: Using `class` instead of `AnyObject` makes it much more clear that the protocol requires the conforming type to be a class IMHO, especially for people new to Swift

Comment: @VladRusu that's completely wrong. `class` is actually just a type alias for `AnyObject`. You are mistaking `AnyObject` for `NSObject`. `AnyObject` is simply a Swift protocol that all classes implicitly conform to, it doesn't mean Obj-C object.

Comment: Just mentioning that “class vs AnyObject protocol” has been discussed here https://stackoverflow.com/q/30176814/1187415 (with some links to the Swift forum).

Comment: @CarlSarkis Yes I think you need to get used to that the compiler error messages can be confusing or misleading :)

Comment: amazing misleading, amazing description. wow.